# Apex Test Class for Inserting Both Parent and Child Objects

Tags: apex, unit-test

Can anyone help me create a test class for this? This apex class inserts both the parent (Custom_object1__c) and multiple child (Custom_Item__c) at the same time. The insertion depends first on the parent object's record types. Most of the topics I've seen focus more on inserting just one object, and I don't know how to insert another which is related to its parent.

Here's my apex controller:

```
public with sharing class MyCustomController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController con;
    public Custom_object1__c customobj {get;set;}
    public List<CustomWrapper> customlist {get;set;} 
    public Integer rowToRemove {get;set;}


    public List<User> userList {get; set;} 
    public String searchTerm {get; set;}
    public String selected {get; set;}
    public String acctname {get; set;} 
    public List <SelectOption> options {get; set;}
    public String selectedRT {get; set;}
    public Boolean form1 {get; set;}
    public Boolean form2 {get; set;} 
    public List<SelectOption> SelectValues {get; set;} 

    public MyCustomController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        con = controller;
        this.customobj = (Custom_object1__c)controller.getRecord();

        form1 = form2 = false;
        selectedRT = '';

        expenselist = new List<CustomWrapper>();
        addNewRowToCustomList();
        if(customobj.Account__c != null) {
            Account accq = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Account WHERE ID =: customobj.Account__c];
            acctname = accq.Name;
        }

    }

    public void addNewRowToCustomList() {
        List<CustomWrapper> temp_customlist = new List<CustomWrapper>();
        CustomWrapper newRecord = new CustomWrapper();
        Custom_Item__c newCustomRecord = new Custom_Item__c();
        newRecord.cit = newCustomRecord;
        newRecord.index = temp_customlist.size();
        temp_customlist.add(newRecord);
        for(CustomWrapper cloop : temp_customlist) {
            customlist.add(cloop);
        }
    }

    public void removeRowFromCustomList() {
        List<CustomWrapper> rem_customlist = new List<CustomWrapper>();
        for(CustomWrapper cloop : customlist) {
            rem_customlist.add(cloop);
        }
        rem_customlist.remove(rowToRemove);
        customlist.clear();
        for(CustomWrapper culoop : rem_customlist) {
            customlist.add(culoop);
        }
    }

    Public PageReference cancel() {

        PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref;
    }

    public PageReference save() {

        List<CustomWrapper> co_customlist = new List<CustomWrapper>();
        List<Custom_Item__c > newCustomsList = new List<Custom_Item__c >();
        Decimal total = 0;
        for(CustomWrapper cloop : customlist) {
            co_customlist.add(cloop);
        }
        system.debug('co_customlist >> ' + co_customlist);
        for(CustomWrapper totalloop : co_customlist) {
            total += totalloop.cit.Amount__c;
            system.debug('totalu >> ' + total);
        }
        system.debug('totalb >> ' + total);
        Custom_object1__c co_custom = new Custom_object1__c();
        co_custom.User__c = selected;
        co_custom.Account__c = customobj.Account__c;
        co_custom.Employee__c = customobj.Employee__c;
        co_custom.Total__c = total;
        insert co_custom;


        if(co_customlist !=null && !co_customlist.isEmpty()) {

            for(CustomWrapper eachRecord : co_customlist) {
                Custom_Item__c cusTemp = new Custom_Item__c ();
                cusTemp.Amount__c = eachRecord.cit.Amount__c;
                cusTemp.Date__c = eachRecord.cit.Date__c;
                cusTemp.Custom_Information__c = eachRecord.cit.Custom_Information__c;
                cusTemp.Custom_Name_Type__c = eachRecord.cit.Custom_Name_Type__c;
                cusTemp.Custom_Name_Type2__c = eachRecord.cit.Custom_Name_Type2__c;

                cusTemp.Custom_object1__c = co_custom.id;
                newCustomsList.add(cusTemp);

            }
        }

        if(newCustomsList.size() > 0) {
            insert newCustomsList;
        }

        PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/' + co_custom.Id);
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref;
    }


    public void onChangeVal(){

        if(selectedRT == 'ABC'){
            form1 = true;
            form2 = false;
        }

        else if(selectedRT == 'DEF'){
            form1 = false;
            form2 = true;
        }

        else{
            form1 = false;
            form2 = false;
        }
    } 

    public class CustomWrapper {

        public Integer index {get;set;}
        public Custom_Item__c cit {get;set;}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is:

```
Parent__c p = new Parent__c();
insert p;
Child__c c = new Child__c(Parent__c = p.Id);
insert c;
```

The explanation is that to hook up a child object you most have the parent Id available and that is not available until after the parent object has been inserted; it is set on the parent object as part of the insert operation. Child objects are related to parents via a foreign key field which in custom objects defaults to the same name as the parent object type name i.e. `Parent__c` in this case. Setting that field hooks the child up to the parent.

(Note that there are also reference fields - ones that end in `__r` - but these are not the mechanism to create the association; they are only populated when the parent and child are queried together.)

Comment: Well, it's [not the only pattern](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2012/03/create-parent-and-child-records-in-one.html).

Comment: @AdrianLarson Fair comment; rephrased.

Comment: Your note at the end still says this style of association is not possible though.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Wiring up reference field doesn't work; adding and setting up external Id fields does. So what's wrong with my note at the end?

Comment: What BB says is that you can in fact use the `__r` fields to specify the relationship using external Id. It looks to me like you're saying you can't use the `__r` fields to specify the relationship?

Comment: @AdrianLarson That's not what I read in his post. A `__r` is a reference (pointer) to the other object. An external Id is an alternate key where you can specify the value at both sides (rather than requiring the Id that is only available after the first object is inserted.

Comment: He essentially says you can `insert new Contact(FirstName='Bob', LastName='Buzzard', Account=new Account(External__c='key'));`. He's using standard relationships, but that means you can set the lookup via the pointer. No?

Comment: @AdrianLarson No, I'm confident you can't. Suggest you try it if you wan to be sure.